# MYSQL - Using Update and Group By together

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-update

This `SELECT` statement gives me the results I want:

```
SELECT submission_archive.id,
       submission_archive.status_id,
       lead.status_id AS job_status_id,
       submission_archive.submission_id,
       lead.id AS lead_id
  FROM submission_archive
  JOIN record
    ON submission_archive.record_id = record.id
  JOIN lead
    ON record.lead_id = lead.id
 WHERE submission_archive.status_id = 1
   AND lead.status_id = 9
 GROUP BY submission_archive.submission_id
```

For these results I want to set `submission_archive.status_id=9` but when I try:

```
UPDATE submission_archive 
  JOIN record 
    ON submission_archive.record_id = record.id 
  JOIN lead 
    ON record.lead_id = lead.id
   SET submission_archive.status_id = 9
 WHERE submission_archive.status_id = 1
   AND submission.status_id = 9 
 GROUP BY submission_archive.submission_id
```

I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'GROUP BY submission_archive.submission_id'

After some looking about, I suspected I might need to use a subquery to achieve the results I want.  I have never done subquerys before, but I had a go with this:

```
UPDATE submission_archive
   SET status_id=9
 WHERE (
        SELECT submission_archive.id
          FROM submission_archive
          JOIN record 
            ON submission_archive.record_id=record.id
          JOIN lead 
            ON record.lead_id=lead.id
         WHERE submission_archive.status_id=1 AND lead.status_id=9
         GROUP BY submission_archive.submission_id  
       )
```

And that got me this error:

> Table 'submission_archive' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

I can perform the `UPDATE` statement without the `GROUP BY` statement, but I need to update only 1 of the records that have matching `submission_id`s - it doesn't matter which one, but it has to be just one of them.

Can anyone help me achieve what I want?  Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, sample data would really be helpful here.  Show us data before and after the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax should like this :

```
UPDATE submission_archive sa1
  JOIN
     (
        SELECT sa.id
          FROM submission_archive sa
          JOIN record r
            ON sa.record_id = r.id
          JOIN lead l
            ON r.lead_id = l.id
         WHERE sa.status_id = 1
           AND l.status_id = 9
         GROUP BY sa.submission_id
       ) sa2   
    ON sa1.id = sa2.id
   SET sa1.status_id = 9
```

containing `[INNER] JOIN` before the subquery instead of `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Perfect - thank you very much!  (You didn't even need a MRE either. Kudos!)